# Use Blender to get "Average" skull shape

Tags: shape-keys

This may be a theoretical question, but I'll ask anyway

I know using Shape Keys I can do morphing like this:
[image]

In other words, I know that Blender can "morph" objects together.  I'm no expert at it, and I've heard that problems are created when objects don't have the same number of faces, etc..., but I know Blender is incredibly powerful and maybe something like this can be done.

Lets say I have two skulls like so:  [image]

Can I "morph" them together to get the halfway point between the two?   And if so, could I expand on that idea to take something like 50 skulls and get the "average" shape of all of them?  Possibly something like the "average skull" they created in matlab in this paper:
https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-018-21662-w

That average of 50 skulls is my ultimate goal (what I'd like answered in this question).

Thank you!

Comment: I would be surprised if this is possible with blender,  but what came to my mind is to place them over and one of them create a shapekey that very roughly adjust in sculpt mode or with proportional editing ... to get  similar shape and them use shrinkwrap modifier and apply as shapekey. But one more thing .... Shapekey moves vertices in straight - shortest way from start end position that sometimes creates very deformed shape in middle part of transition.

Comment: Can you share source meshes to experiment with? I’ve done something similar involving a common texture on different meshes. It might be possible to adapt that approach to averaging meshes.